# Dijkstra's algorithm not adding end node (C++)

Tags: c++, dijkstra

I have been experimenting with implementing Dijkstra's algorithm in C++ and used this pseudocode from wikipedia as a start:

```
 1  function Dijkstra(Graph, source):
 2      
 3      for each vertex v in Graph.Vertices:
 4          dist[v] ← INFINITY
 5          prev[v] ← UNDEFINED
 6          add v to Q
 7      dist[source] ← 0
 8      
 9      while Q is not empty:
10          u ← vertex in Q with min dist[u]
11          remove u from Q
12          
13          for each neighbor v of u still in Q:
14              alt ← dist[u] + Graph.Edges(u, v)
15              if alt < dist[v] and dist[u] is not INFINITY:
16                  dist[v] ← alt
17                  prev[v] ← u
18
19      return dist[], prev[]
```

While also using this tutorial and the C++ code as a template/help: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dijkstras-shortest-path-algorithm-greedy-algo-7/.

I have since then tried to expand the code to not just find the distance from source to each vertex, but instead just trying to find the shortest path from **source** to a **target**. Tried this by implementing pseudocode from wikipedia for that:

*If we are only interested in a shortest path between vertices source and target, we can terminate the search after line 10 if u = target. Now we can read the shortest path from source to target by reverse iteration:*

```
1  S ← empty sequence
2  u ← target
3  if prev[u] is defined or u = source:          // Do something only if the vertex is reachable
4      while u is defined:                       // Construct the shortest path with a stack S
5          insert u at the beginning of S        // Push the vertex onto the stack
6          u ← prev[u]                           // Traverse from target to sourc
```

This is my current code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
#include <limits.h>

#define V 9

int minDistance(int dist[], bool prev[])
{
    // Initialize min value
    int min = INT_MAX, min_index;
 
    for (int v = 0; v < V; v++)
        if (prev[v] == false && dist[v] <= min)
            min = dist[v], min_index = v;
 
    return min_index;
}

void printSolution(int dist[])
{
    cout <<"Vertex \t Distance from Source" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
        cout  << i << " \t\t"<<dist[i]<< endl;
}

void dijkstra(int graph[V][V], int src, int target) {
    
    int dist[V];
    int prev[V];
    bool Q[V];
    //bool true_target = false;
    int S[V];

    for (int i=0; i < V; i++) {
        dist[i] = INT_MAX;
        prev[i] = INT_MAX;
        // add v to Q
        Q[i] = false;
    }
    dist[src] = 0;

    //while Q is not empty:
    for (int count = 0; count < V-1; count++) {
        int u = minDistance(dist, Q);
        cout << "u: " << u << endl;
        vector<int> S;
        //true_target = (u==target);
        if (u == target) {
            if ((prev[u] != INT_MAX) || (u = src)) {
                while(u > 0) {
                    cout << u << endl;
                    S.push_back(u);
                    u = prev[u];
                }
                cout << "END" << endl;
                for (auto j = S.begin(); j != S.end(); ++j) {
                    cout << *j << ' ';
                }
                return;
            }
        }
        Q[u] = true;

        for (int v = 0; v < V; v++) {
            //cout << graph[u][v] << endl;
            if (!Q[v] && graph[u][v] && dist[u] != INT_MAX && dist[u] + graph[u][v] < dist[v]) {
                dist[v] = dist[u] + graph[u][v];
                prev[v] = u;
            }
        }
    }

    printSolution(dist);
}

int main ()
 {

     int graph[V][V] = {{0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0},
                        {4, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0},
                        {0, 8, 0, 7, 0, 4, 0, 0, 2},
                        {0, 0, 7, 0, 9, 14, 0, 0, 0},
                        {0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0},
                        {0, 0, 4, 14, 10, 0, 2, 0, 0},
                        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 6},
                        {8, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 7},
                        {0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6, 7, 0}};

     dijkstra(graph, 0, 4);

     return 0;
 }
```

My main problem is that vertex 4, the vertex farthest away from the source, is not a vertex my current code can find a path to. When trying to find a path to 4 the output is:

```
u: 0
u: 1
u: 7
u: 6
u: 5
u: 2
u: 8
u: 3
Vertex   Distance from Source
0               0
1               4
2               12
3               19
4               21
5               11
6               9
7               8
8               14
```

Showing that an u: 4 is never generated, unlike trying to find a path to 5:

```
u: 0
u: 1
u: 7
u: 6
u: 5
5
6
7
END
5 6 7
```

That find u: 5 and shows a path back to source.

Appreciate any help. Thanks ^^

Comment: That GFG site is notorious for bad code, bad examples, and bad explanations.  It's too bad that so many new C++ programmers go there to learn C++.  The second thing is this -- [debug your code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) -- use a debugger to see where the code you wrote diverges from the plan you wrote on paper.

Comment: I would not write code like that, at no place in your code the size of the passed arrays can be checked. Have a look at `std::vector` or `std::array` for passing arrays (preferably const&)